# pie chart in ggplot text labelling horror

Tags: r, ggplot2

I can't resolve that strange situation. Somewhere I have error, or bug, but sitting over three halfs of an hour could not deal with it.

I have: `sta_df`

```
             sta value
1 IN_LIQUIDATION    29
2     LIQUIDATED    47
3      OPERATING   435
4    TRANSFORMED     8

sp <- ggplot(sta_df, aes(x="", y=value, fill=sta)) +
  geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity", color = "black") +
  coord_polar("y") + scale_fill_brewer(palette="Pastel2") +
  geom_text(aes(x = seq(1.2,1.4,,4), label = percent(value/sum(value))), 
                position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size=5)
```

and the plot have wrong direction of labelling.

[image]

Nevermind this strange font of a picture. I've tried to use many different functions instead of `position_stack`. For example:

`geom_text(aes(x = rep(seq(0.9,1.4,,6),1), y = value/2 + c(0, cumsum(value)[-length(value)])`

but it didn't help. This thread neither: [wrong labeling in ggplot pie chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41661654/wrong-labeling-in-ggplot-pie-chart)

When I wanted to reverse `y=rev(value)` the legend didn't correspond with data. Putting direction `1` or `-1` doesn't do more than reversing all. Reversing values in `geom_text` gives Pac-Man-like chart. I've updated `ggplot2`.

Honestly, the problem is because chart starts to draw anti-clockwise although direction is set to clockwise and text numbers are in right direction. And reversing data in data.frame doesn't change anything in the whole plot. Sorry, I stuck, but feel the solution is right there.

Answer (score 2):

The problem occurs when you assign different x-values to your labels in `geom_label()`. Why? Because you are relying on `position_stack()` to give you your y-values. But when the points no longer share the same x, then they don't get 'stacked' anymore. If you want to customize the x-values, you will need to compute your own y-values, as described here ([Showing data values on stacked bar chart in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644997/showing-data-values-on-stacked-bar-chart-in-ggplot2)) and here (http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_text.html) near bottom of the page. By the way, I did all my troubleshooting with `coord_polar` removed, just looking at the plain barplot version.

Anyway, here is a partial solution:

```
sta_df <- read.table(header=TRUE,
text="     sta value
IN_LIQUIDATION    29
LIQUIDATED        47
OPERATING        435
TRANSFORMED        8")

library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

sta_df$fraction = sta_df$value / sum(sta_df$value)

sp <- ggplot(sta_df, aes(x="", y=value, fill=sta)) +
      geom_bar(width=1, stat="identity", color="black",) +
      scale_fill_brewer(palette="Pastel2") +
      coord_polar(theta="y") +
      geom_text(aes(x=1.4, label=percent(fraction)), 
                position=position_stack(vjust=0.5), size=4)

ggsave("pie_chart.png", plot=sp, height=4, width=6, dpi=150)
```

[image]

Comment: Ok. Many thanks! You answered my question, indeed, but this is the most important issue to variate x values, because texts are overlapping (in real charts, not this example). Calculating these values are quite tricky, and I'd need some hints, but probably in another threats. Thanks.